# 403 Forbidden "These credentials do not authorize access" for HERE Geocoding & Search API

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Currently working on building an address validator for a project I am working on, currently using a HERE account with a credit card attached for usage with the HERE Geocoding and Search API.

A minimal example to get started, a request to `https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=eiffel+tower&apiKey={{apikey}}` is returning the following;

```json
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

I've confirmed the API key to be functional, as a request to the older API, like so `https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=eiffel+tower&apiKey={{apikey}}` does work and returns expected results.

I'd like to use this API specifically, as it will be interfacing with a system that uses this version of the HERE API, and would like to maintain parity.

The [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html) states that either API Key or OAuth are acceptable to use, and according to the [linked identity & access management guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/plat-using-apikeys.html), this is done by simply adding the apikey query parameter, as seen in the working 6.2 example.

Other questions on the matter state that this code is returned when the endpoint is not usable on a base plan, however [the pricing page](https://www.here.com/pricing) indicates this should be usable on a free account up to 5000 requests.

Comment: Please share your app id for us to check.

Comment: App ID is "dSJWvHNSuOdZQqU8zMih"

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport App ID is "dSJWvHNSuOdZQqU8zMih"

Comment: We're having a similar issues except for accessing Routes v7. v8 and geocoding v1 work fine.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Does nto seem to be very active on SO, even though they refer to this website :-(

Comment: Try to contact the HERE team directly via https://developer.here.com/help - usually, they reply super fast.

Answer (score 2):

You have linked your app_id, which are using is linked to as specific project.Because of this you are not able to use this app_id in the geocode service.

Please make sure that the app is linked to No project in the access manager as shown in the below screen.

[image]