# Submit batch geocoding request to here api returns credentials do not authorize

Tags: here-api

As suggested in the developer [guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/submit-batch-request.html) i try to submit a batch gecoding request:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary @addresses.txt "https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?&apiKey=XXXX&action=run&header=true&inDelim=;&outDelim=,&outCols=recId,latitude,longitude,locationLabel&outputcombined=true&language=de-DE"

Thist returns an error:

{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}

appID is tzYeXNnAAB1SpyghxOcO

My apiKey is OK, it works with

https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=eiffel+tower&apiKey=XXXX
or
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=eiffel+tower&apiKey=XXXX

I subscribed to the here Base Plan, created a project, created an app and an apiKey, added the app to the project.
->Error

I tried app without default project (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791636/403-forbidden-these-credentials-do-not-authorize-access-for-here-geocoding-s))  ->same error

Here answered:
"Looks like the APP ID is generated on HERE Platform where Batch Geocoder API is not yet available. It is scheduled to be made available in Q2 2023."

Where else can i generate an apiKey working for Batch Geocoder if not in the HERE Platform?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Batch Geocoder API only if you already have a developer account in place on developer.here.com and the API key is generated there.

As of now, the new account creation is restricted on developer portal and we are in the process of migrating everything to HERE Platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@martmyr

I had the same issue, I can confirm that if you have an old apiKey (mine is 1 year old) it still works (using https://developer.here.com/)

While the new apiKey was created using https://platform.here.com/ and it is working with almost other api endpoints other than Batch Geocoder endpoint