# Batch geocoding with Here maps API - These credentials do not authorize access

Tags: here-api

I have been using Here Batch Geocoding API for a long time (since 2021). However, my credentials stopped working in March and I needed to create a new API key on platform.here.com. It worked for some time (a few weeks).

However, yesterday I tried to use the API with both the old API keys (developer.here.com) and the new API keys (platform.here.com), but none of them work. I always get this error below.

{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}

I think this may be related to the migration from developer to platform.here.com, but I am not sure.

I tried contacting Here through their support at platform.here.com but still no answer.

I noticed the post below is the same issue, but as I mentioned I do have API keys both at the old and the new platforms, but they don't work.
[Submit batch geocoding request to here api returns credentials do not authorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825420/submit-batch-geocoding-request-to-here-api-returns-credentials-do-not-authorize)

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe

I had the same issue, I can confirm that if you have an old apiKey (mine is 1 year old and generated using https://developer.here.com/) the 403 error won't return, but still all the records sent will be displayed as an error in
response 
and the response file will have no records

While the new apiKey was created using https://platform.here.com/ and it is working with almost other api endpoints other than Batch Geocoder endpoint

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I have both old (developer.here.com) and new apiKeys (created at platform.here.com). However, I get the same error regardless of the apikeys used

Comment: Hi Felipe,
I don't think it will make much difference, because in the end, regardless of the API key you use the Batch Geocoder endpoint won't return results.

When I used the old API key, the request was accepted and marked as completed after few seconds but marked all records as errors and so returned an empty file.

It seems like the issue is from their side because of the migration to the new platform

Comment: I have noticed that they are upgrading their API version from 6 to 7, so it seems like bulk Reverse Geocoding is not available yet but only single Reverse Geocoding Requests

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/migration-geocoder/topics-api/multi-reverse-geocoding.html

Comment: Ahmed. You are right. I contacted Here and they confirmed that batch geocoding is not yet available in the new platform.

Comment: Felipe, FYI, I found out that if I subscribed to HERE services from aws marketplace I could have up to 250,000 requests per month which was more than enough for me, I have sent more than 10 requests per second without any issues, so maybe that could be a turnaround solution till they fix the batch endpoint.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-hlc5los56uj3q?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have just subscribed to HERE through AWS and I could generate new apikeys. However, I still get the 'forbidden' error.